# Why doesn't ASP.net MVC automatically decode POST (aka Form) parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've done some basic tests with System.Net.WebClient and an ASP.net MVC 3 website and I've found that when binding to the parameters of an action, MVC will automatically decode any query string parameters that have been UrlEncoded if you use GET.  But it won't automatically decode POST parameters.  Is there a reason for this?  Seems like a needless inconvenience.

Comment: It will, checkout model binding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC default model binder uses the `Request.Form` provider to read POST values. This provider also automatically decodes url encoded parameters.

For example if you send the following POST payload:

```
foo=%26&bar=%3D
```

in the corresponding controller action you will get the correct values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string foo, string bar)
{
    // foo equals &
    // bar equals =
}
```

So you probably are not correctly url encoding the request.

Comment: Thanks Darin. You're right.

It turns out I was doubly encoding my test param, "doesn&#039;t", because I didn't realize that WebClient.UploadValues encodes the params for you. If I didn't URL encode before calling UploadValues, i.e. the param was only encoded once, I got a "potentially dangerous request" error because of my test value.

I thought URL encoding would take care of any such error, so that really threw a wrench into my test/understanding.  Thanks again.

Comment: +1 Just found this.  Needed to know if it automatically decoded and that is exactly what I found.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery.Post and sending the data as POST data using the data parameter as in below snippet, then jquery would automatically encode for you.

```
 var postdata = {
            url: someUrl, //do not encodeURIComponent, it's done by jquery.post. test with some edge url if in doubt
           };

        $.post(serverUrl, postdata)
            .done(function (data) {
            };
```

If you also encode yourself, then you will get double encoded data. Asp.net controller parameter is always decoded once whether in case of get or post.